# jQuery animate not working on left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new with jQuery and I'm trying to do something quite simple, but it looks like it's not that simple.

I have a menu inside a DIV, the DIV has a width of 500px and the menu of 250px. Over the menu I put a button. The idea is that when someone click on the button the menu goes from the left of the DIV to the right.

Well, it's not working.

A Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KUR52/ and the code:

```
<div class="menuWrap">

        <a href="#" class="button"> MENU </a>

        <nav class="menu">

            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
              <li>Aenean commodo</li>
              <li>Aenean massa</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Aenean</li>
              <li>Aenean massa</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
              <li>Aenean </li>
              <li>Aenean massa cum </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.menuWrap {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
    .menu {
        position: relative;
     /* left:250px; */
        left:0;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: orange;
    }
        .menu ul{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style:none;
        }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('.menu').toggle(function () {

                $(this).animate({left:'250px'}, 300)

            }, function () {

                $(this).animate({left:'0px'}, 300)

            }

            );
        });
});
```

I found a couple of possible solutions but i'm not able to make them work, the most promising was this: [jQuery - animating 'left' position of absolutely positioned div when sliding panel is revealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665368/jquery-animating-left-position-of-absolutely-positioned-div-when-sliding-pan) But it didn't took me vary far, mostly because I don't understand `parseInt` and how to use the value I get from it.
This is my fail attempt http://jsfiddle.net/W5avM/

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you want something like this :  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/GC2Av/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to use `toggle` event method, you are misusing this function and also it has been removed from jQuery 1.9. You are using `toggle` effect method that hides your element and doesn't accept 2 callback functions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').click(function () {
        var $menu = $('.menu'),
            val = $menu.css('left') === '250px' ? '0px' : '250px';
        $menu.animate({
            left: val
        }, 300)
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hh5nH/

Comment: That works perfect! Can you give me a little explanation of the 4 line? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`toggle()` displays or hides an element. I don't think that is the method you are looking for.

You might want to use `toggleClass` to change the class on the menu, and set the different position states in CSS. This can be animated using CSS3 transitions. Alternatively, you can bind the click event to a handler which:

1. Checks the current position.
2. Depending on the current position, animates the menu to the alternate state

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get you started:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.menu').animate({left:'250px'}, 300);    
});
```